# Конвертер видео с YouTube в MP3 файлы

Tags: ajax, php

Добрый день. У меня такой вопрос: как реализовать "online youtube to mp3 converter" с помощью php?

Comment: То есть, извлечь звук из видео и конвертировать его в mp3 (при необходимости)?

Comment: Да например http://www.flvto.com/

Comment: Так найди сервис, где можно встраивать к себе на страницу. Думаю есть такие.

Answer (score 8):

Обычно это делается так.
На php/python (другом любимом языке) пишется оболочка для загрузки файлов. После загрузки файла на сервер, специальная программа на сервере начинает его преобразование. А когда преобразование завершено, скрипт показывает ссылку на скачку.

Для преобразований обычно используют ffmpeg, который есть репозитариях практически каждого дистрибутива. Но возможно, для лучшей производительности, Вам придется собрать его для себя самостоятельно.

Вот для затравки пример, как можно извлечь звуковую дорожку:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.flv -acodec copy output.mp3
```

Почему сам скрипт не занимается пробразованием? а потому что скрипты для веба не должны долго и тяжело работать. Да и апач по умолчанию ограничивает время работы скрипта 30 секундами.

Общая схема работы системы.
Пользователь выбрал файл и загрузил его на сервер. Скрипт скопировал его в директорию для преобразований. А также добавил в базу запись о том, что такой то файл, такому то пользователю (можно использовать сессии или регистрацию пользователя).

Спец программа будет где то такая:

```
повторять:
    проверить, есть ли записи в базе
    если нет, подождать немного и перейти в начало цикла
    иначе:
        извлечь очередное задание
        пометить его как "в прогрессе"
        запустить ffmpeg на преобразование.
        если преобразование завершено удачно
            скопировать результат
            пометить  в базе "все ок" и прописать ссылку на результат
        иначе:
            пометить в базе "все плохо"
        удалить начальный файл
     перейти в начало цикла
```

Вебчасть, после того, как добавила файл на обработку просто запускает обновление страницы с интервалом в несколько секунд/минут (тут нужно подобрать) проверяет статус в базе и показывает прогресс.